# How does this function that verify if a informed name is equal to other name works

Tags: c, substring, c-strings, function-definition

I've been looking for codes in C that verify if two strings are equal. I found this one but I don't understand the logic in the `for` and the `while` parts.

```
int verify(phonebook name[],char name_verify[])
{
    int i,k;

    char *p,temp[strlen(name_verify)];

    if(strlen(name) >= strlen(name_verify))
    {
        for(i=0; i<=(strlen(name) - strlen(name_verify)) ; i++)
        {
            p=&name[i];
            k=0;
            
            while(k!=strlen(name_verify))
            {
                temp[k] =* (p + k);
                k++;
            }
            temp[k]='\0';

            if(strcmp(strupr(temp),strupr(name_verify))==0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Could someone explain to me how it works?

Comment: The code checks whether the string name_verify is a substring of the string name independent on the case of letters.

Comment: can u explain me why this code is bad?

Comment: At least because the function strlen is called several times for same strings. Also there are used variable that are not declared in scopes where they are used. And the array temp is redundant.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow how this part works `temp[k] =* (p + k);`  i didnt get it because p is a type of char pointer and its summing with a integer type.

Comment: It is the same as temp[k] = p[k]; where the pointer p points to a substring of the string name starting from the index i.

Comment: Pay attention tp that it is unclear how the type specifier phonebook is defined that also makes the function less readable.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the code itself is pretty generic. It is not bad but is inefficient at least because, as you said, it uses *strlen* in iterations.  Also it uses *strupr* every iteration. Using of 'temp' can also be avoided toward a more efficient *strncmp*.

Comment: @Serge Theoretically the compiler could optimize out the redundant `strlen()` and `strupr()` calls. `temp` is necessary because `strupr()` modifies the string in place.

Comment: @Barmar temp is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Right, and so is `strupr()`. You can use `strnicmp()` to perform a case-insensitive substring comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the declaration of the function

```
int verify(phonebook name[],char name_verify[])
```

confusing because it is not clear what the type specifier `phonebook` means. So the reader of the function needs to investigate the function body to assume that `phonebook` is a synonym for the type `char`.

This declaration of a variable length array

```
char *p,temp[strlen(name_verify)];
```

can be a reason of undefined behavior because it does not have a space to store the terminating zero character '\0' of the string `name_verify`.

You have to write

```
char *p,temp[strlen(name_verify) + 1];
```

But using a variable length array can be a reason of a stack overflow. Using this array is entirely redundant. The function can be written without it.

Within the function there are numerous redundant calls of the function `strlen`.

The function tries to check whether the string `name` contains within itself a substring that is equal to the string `name_verify` if to convert the both to upper case.

At first the function checks that the length of the string `name` is not less than the length of the string `name_verify`.

```
if(strlen(name) >= strlen(name_verify))
```

Then in the for loop

```
for(i=0; i<=(strlen(name) - strlen(name_verify)) ; i++)
```

it starts to traverse the string name and determine whether the substring starting from the index i in the string name is equal to the string name_verify.

For this purpose the substring of the string name is copied in the array temp

```
        p=&name[i];
        k=0;
        
        while(k!=strlen(name_verify))
        {
            temp[k] =* (p + k);
            k++;
        }
        temp[k]='\0';
```

After the copy is finished the formed string in the array temp is compared in upper case with the string `name_verify`.

```
        if(strcmp(strupr(temp),strupr(name_verify))==0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
```

If they are equal the function return 1.

Otherwise if there is no such a substring in the string `name` that is equal to `name_verify` it seems the function returns `0` in a return statement that is not shown in the provided code.:)

Answer (score 0):

With respect to "This is a bad code", I'd say that the main reason is that it is unnecessarily complex for what it does, so much so that it I could believe that it has been intentionally obfuscated, and it does not make use of the obvious standard library functions that would apply.  To demonstrate, here is one way I might write the function:

```
int verify(const char name[], char name_verify[]) {
    char temp = strdup(name);
    int result = ((strstr(strupr(temp), strupr(name_verify))) != NULL);

    free(temp);
    return result ;
}
```

That's (so much!) cleaner and clearer.

If you happen not to have `strdup()` (which is specified by POSIX, not the C language specification) then you can always implement your own:

```
char *strdup(const char *src) {
    char *result = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);

    if (result) {
        strcpy(result, src);
    }

    return result;
}
```